# Change value of shell variables as an argument of npm run command

Tags: bash, shell, npm-scripts

I am trying to accomplish the following -> Right now I use cypress to run e2e tests. It is being launched by npm command. I have several environments and different user permission. I created a shell script, where I have stored value of environment and user permission rights. What I want to do is to have opportunity to run npm command with parameters to change the value of variable from shell script. Could someone give a clue, is it even possible? The expected behaviour is to write something like:

```
npm run cy dev3,full
```

And have the opportunity to change the value of shell script variable to launch necessary environament and change value of user permissions.

package.json command:

```
"scripts": {
    "cy": "./scripts/cypress.sh",
}
```

cypress.sh file content

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DEV_ENV="${DEV_ENV:-"dev3"}"
USER_TYPE="${USER_TYPE:-"full"}"

COMMAND="cypress open \
--browser chrome \
--config baseUrl=https://environment-$DEV_ENV.com \
--env DEV_ENV=https://environment-$DEV_ENV.com,USER_TYPE=$USER_TYPE
"
eval $COMMAND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the environment variables seen in `cypress.sh`? If so, you can just execute `npm run` like this:

```sh
DEV_ENV=dev2 USER_TYPE=empty npm run cy
```

and it will change the value of `DEV_ENV` and `USER_TYPE`.

If you want to strictly run it by using the format you gave (`npm run cy dev3,full`), the args `dev3,full` are passed on to `cypress.sh`, so you can just parse the arguments directly in `cypress.sh`:

```sh
if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
  # do whatever here...
fi
```